# C# " System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The requested address is not valid in its context.' "

Tags: c#, udp

I am trying to send and receive some integers through UDP. If I make the IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1") it is all good, I do not confront with any difficulty. Hovewer, if I make the IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44") , I get the error called
" System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'The requested address is not valid in its context.' "
on the line where I bind the socket.

Here is the sender code;

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress clientIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44"); // 
IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(clientIP, 273);
clientSocket.Bind(clientEndPoint);          
IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44");
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, 673);
byte[] bytesToSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(24);
clientSocket.SendTo(bytesToSend, serverEndPoint);
clientSocket.Close();
```

Here is the receiver code;

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44");
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, 673);
serverSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[4];
serverSocket.Receive(receivedBytes);
richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");
richTextBox1.AppendText(BitConverter.ToInt32(receivedBytes).ToString());
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
serverSocket.Close();
```

I somehow managed to send int through UDP using Connect instead of Bind.

Here is the code;

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPAddress clientIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44"); // 
IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(clientIP, 273);
clientSocket.Connect(clientEndPoint);          
IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.44");
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, 673);
byte[] bytesToSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(24);
clientSocket.SendTo(bytesToSend, serverEndPoint);
clientSocket.Close();
```

This is working, perfectly sends the data, but it did not work for receiver code.

PS: Is there any way to send the integer value to the  "192.168.2.44" IP? **I should not use IPAddress.Any or 0.0.0.0.** Or is there any way to call other programming language function to get the value from that IP address then get the result to the C# ?

Comment: `192.168.2.44` is a local private IP address which is either assigned by your router or is the routers own local IP address

Comment: "I should not use IPAddress.Any" why not? That is the correct answer for the local endpoint, you shouldn't be specifying the local address to bind to.